# Filter and Query in React

Tags: reactjs, api, select

I have the following code in FilterList.js and List.js. All I want is if I select all at first and then deselect one by one in the supplier filter, the supplier query is not passed in API end-point until I reach id less than 200. And after I reach id less than 200, the supplier query is passed.

ListFilter.js

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  PrimaryButton,
  SecondaryButton,
} from "components/__v2__/Button/ReusableButton";
import Search from "components/Search";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Clear, Settings } from "@material-ui/icons";
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";
import { Box, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import InputField from "components/atoms/InputField";
// import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import MaterialIcon from "@material/react-material-icon";
import AsyncSelect from "components/atoms/AsyncSelect";

import useGet from "hooks/useGet";
import useCheckPermission from "hooks/useCheckPermission";
import { ImportIcon } from "../../ResourceAssigner/SvgIcons";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import AsyncSelectColumnFilter from "components/MyTable/Filters/AsyncSelectColumnFilter";
import Select from "components/atoms/Select";

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  button: {
    fontSize: "12px",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginLeft: "10px",
  },
  clearIcon: {
    fontSize: "18px",
  },
}));

const EquipmentListFilter = ({
  searchText,
  searchHandler,
  fetchEquipmentsList,
  perPage,
  pageNumber,
  typeFilter,
  setTypeFilter,
  supplierFilter,
  setSupplierFilter,
}) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const isAddAllowed = useCheckPermission(
    (user) => user?.data?.equipment?.can_add_equipment
  );
  // const [shouldPassQuery, setShouldPassQuery] = useState(true);

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <>
      <Box
        mt={2}
        mb={2}
        display="flex"
        justifyContent="space-between"
        flexWrap="wrap"
        style={{ gap: 8 }}
        className="resource_assigner_filter"
      >
        <Box display="flex" style={{ gap: 8 }}>
          <Box style={{ minWidth: 200 }}>
            <AsyncSelect
              isMulti
              showNumbers
              placeholder="Type: "
              isClearable={false}
              value={typeFilter}
              resourceURL="/v1.1/equipment_type/get_list/"
              onChange={(e) => setTypeFilter(e)}
            />
          </Box>
          {typeFilter?.length > 0 && (
            <Button
              variant="text"
              startIcon={<Clear className={classes.clearIcon} />}
              className={classes.button}
              onClick={() => {
                setTypeFilter([]);
              }}
            >
              Clear
            </Button>
          )}
          <Box style={{ minWidth: 200 }}>
            <AsyncSelect
              isMulti
              showNumbers
              placeholder="Suppliers: "
              isClearable={false}
              value={supplierFilter}
              // resourceURL="/v1.1/equipment_supplier/"
              resourceURL="/v1.1/equipment_supplier/"
              onChange={(e) => setSupplierFilter(e)}
            />
          </Box>
          {supplierFilter?.length > 0 && (
            <Button
              variant="text"
              startIcon={<Clear className={classes.clearIcon} />}
              className={classes.button}
              onClick={() => {
                setSupplierFilter([]);
                setSelectedIds([]);
              }}
            >
              Clear
            </Button>
          )}
        </Box>

        <Box display="flex" style={{ gap: 8 }}>
          <Box>
            <InputField
              style={{
                border: "1px solid rgba(206, 210, 217, 0.9)",
                borderRaduis: "4px",
              }}
              value={searchText}
              onChange={searchHandler}
              endAdornment={<MaterialIcon icon="search" />}
              placeholder="Search equipment"
            />
          </Box>
          {/* <SecondaryButton
            variant="outlined"
            startIcon={<ImportIcon fill="#5F6D83" />}
            label="Import"
            size="small"
          /> */}
          {isAddAllowed && (
            <SecondaryButton
              variant="outlined"
              label="Equipment Type"
              startIcon={<Settings />}
              size="small"
              onClick={() => history.push("/settings/equipment-type/")}
            />
          )}
          {isAddAllowed && (
            <PrimaryButton
              onClick={() => history.push("/equipment/add")}
              label=" Add Equipment"
              startIcon={<AddIcon />}
              size="small"
            />
          )}
          <SecondaryButton
            onClick={() => history.push("/equipment/bulk-import")}
            label="Import"
            startIcon={<ImportIcon />}
            size="small"
            variant="outlined"
          />
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

export default EquipmentListFilter;
```

List.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { Portal } from "@material-ui/core";
import HeaderMenuTextWithFrontArrow from "components/__v2__/HeaderMenuTextWithFrontArrow";
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import EquipmentListFilter from "./EquipmentListFilter";
import EquipmentListTable from "./EquipmentListTable/EquipmentListTable";
import useGet from "../../../hooks/useGet";
import useDebounce from "../../../hooks/useDebounce";
import useUser from "../../../hooks/useUser";

const EquipmentList = () => {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = React.useState(null);
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = React.useState(1);
  const [perPage, setPerPageHandler] = React.useState(
    () => localStorage.getItem("per_page") || 25
  );
  const [typeFilter, setTypeFilter] = React.useState([]);
  const [supplierFilter, setSupplierFilter] = React.useState([]);

  const { navLinkRef } = useUser();
  const { push } = useHistory();
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const pageName = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (pathname?.match("/equipment")) return "Equipment";
    return "";
  }, [pathname]);

  useDebounce(
    () => {
      fetchEquipmentsList({
        query: {
          q: searchText,
          type: typeFilter.map((args) => args.id),
          //  supplier: supplierFilter.map((args) => args.id),

          supplier:
            supplierFilter.length > 200
              ? undefined
              : supplierFilter.map((args) => args.id),
          page: pageNumber,
          per_page: perPage,
        },
      });
    },
    1000,
    [searchText]
  );

  const {
    data: equipmentsList,
    fetch: fetchEquipmentsList,
    loading,
  } = useGet("/v1.1/equipment/", {
    query: {
      q: "",
      type: typeFilter.map((args) => args.id),
      // supplier: supplierFilter.map((args) => args.id),
      supplier:
        supplierFilter.length > 200
          ? undefined
          : supplierFilter.map((args) => args.id),
      page: pageNumber,
      per_page: perPage,
    },
  });

  const searchHandler = (e) => {
    setSearchText(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Portal container={navLinkRef.current}>
        <HeaderMenuTextWithFrontArrow onButtonClick={false} text={pageName} />
      </Portal>
      <EquipmentListFilter
        {...{
          searchText,
          searchHandler,
          typeFilter,
          setTypeFilter,
          fetchEquipmentsList,
          perPage,
          pageNumber,
          supplierFilter,
          setSupplierFilter,
        }}
      />
      <EquipmentListTable
        {...{
          searchText,
          equipmentsList,
          fetchEquipmentsList,
          pageNumber,
          setPageNumber,
          perPage,
          setPerPageHandler,
          loading,
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default EquipmentList;
```

In the supplier filter, first I select all options where all the ids of suppliers are passed and then deselect it one by one. The query supplier should not be passed until there won't be id less than 200.